# 20.04 how to use Adobe Connect in Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, adobe

I need Adobe Connect for some meetings. How can I install and use adobe connect in Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This really depends on the server's adobe connect version  but you could try adding:

```
&proto=true
```

to the end of the url.

So for example

```
https://adobe.connect/rn2eXts5e1b7/?session=somebreezsessionID
```

would become

```
https://adobe.connect/rn2eXts5e1b7/?session=somebreezsessionID&proto=true
```

Then click 'Open in Browser' button. I guess this way, you see the HTML version of adobe connect.

Comment: THANKS A LOT but I want to open the meeting in a aplication not in a web browser

Answer (score 9):

I found an easy way to do it. Just install the latest version of [Ruffle](https://ruffle.rs/) for your browser of choice. It is a Flashplayer alternative written in Rust and works perfectly. Hope that works for you!

Comment: savior! thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

hi it worked for me my OS is ubuntu 20.04 so
just add  the bellow

```
?html-view=true
```

to the end of the url.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-connect/kb/install-connect-meeting-add-ubuntu.html)
Last Published: March 10, 2012

To share your screen or documents in an Adobe Connect room, first install the Connect Add-in. Previously, the Add-in was only available to Windows and Mac OS users. But with Adobe Connect 8, Adobe has extended support to Linux via Ubuntu. At this time, Ubuntu version 10.04 (or Lucid Lynx) is the only supported version of Linux.

To verify that your Ubuntu version supports the Add-in, select System, and then click About Ubuntu.
About Ubuntu

If the Ubuntu version listed is 10.04, as in the screenshot above, proceed with the installation.

```
Install Adobe Flash Player version 10.x if you have not done so already. The installation procedure is listed on the Flash Player 10 website at  www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/productinfo/instructions/#section-3. Follow the .deb installation instructions.
Open a browser, log in to Connect, and navigate to the Resources section. Click Getting Started, and then click Downloads. 
Save to a location you can remember.
Double-click ConnectAddin.deb.
Follow the onscreen installer instructions.
Go to Flash Player Settings or right-click on any instance of Flash Player.
Click Global Security Settings Panel.
In the Global Security Settings Panel, select Always Allow.
Reenter the meeting URL into your browser. The Add-in automatically launches and you join the meeting.
If the Add-in does not launch, close all browsers and relaunch the meeting in a new browser session.
```

Comment: Hi there, could you please provide a link to where you found this information? It help provide context and can lead to other information that OP might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

I use chrome for accessing our classes by adobe connect in Ubuntu. So install it from [here](https://www.google.com/chrome/). ( dont use apt-get or  other tools, please just use the package from google website).
there are two problems before you can use web-base  adobe connect in ubuntu.
first, flash playing is deprecated on chrome and other browsers. In order to use flash playing, I would recommand using chrome with a plugin called Ruffle. [Ruffle](https://ruffle.rs/) is a flash emulator plugin. Easily, add Ruffle extension in to your browser from [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ruffle/donbcfbmhbcapadipfkeojnmajbakjdc). Now you can play flash on your chrome browser.
Second, when you add Adobe Connect URL to your browser, you should tell the browser that you want to run Adobe connect in your browser. For this, you should add &proto=true at the end of your Adobe Connect link. (Caution: after passing your credentials on login page, URL address is changed to the long url to which then you should add &proto=true). For example:
http://blabla.com/Tra1596?meeting-passcode=%24%24%3A%3AnMgqpxMRxj54kTAU%2FwiDDQ%3D%3D%3A%3A8l8inc3HLzuBgyTzkUEwsg%3D%3D&OWASP_CSRFTOKEN=5aa8918711e99c8dc63cdf2535ade7fb1f5ef6e3e4c133e07a1596964065361b&proto=true
Now scroll down and click on “Open In Browser”.
If you dont see the long URL after passing your credentail, you should clear your cookies for your Adobe Connect link.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the [user-agent plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/user-agent-string-switcher/) to Firefox. After you've added the plugin, change the agent to the mobile version. Now, you can visit all the adobe contact links.

Description:

> Spoof websites trying to gather information about your web navigation—like your browser type and operating system—to deliver distinct content you may not want.